# python crash course making django posts accessible to unregistered users

Tags: python, django

Im currently trying to do this exercise of python crash course and am unsure with how to proceed with it. Here is the exercise in question.

```
Then try adding a more advanced feature,
such as giving users the option of making a topic public. This would require an
attribute called public as part of the Topic model (this should be set to False
by default) and a form element on the new_topic page that allows the user to
change a topic from private to public.
```

Here are the changes that I have already made so far
in forms.py, My understanding is that when the user types in the 'public' text bos either 'True' or 'False', the public attribute of the Topic model will be updated accordingly?

```
from django import forms

from .models import Topic, Entry

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text', 'public']
        labels = {'text': '', 'public' : "True/False"}

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': 'Entry:'}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

the Topic model in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text
```

My current guess is that in views.py under the topics function I have to edit it such that it tests for either the owner id, or whether the viewer has not been logged in, and then returns all the public topics accordingly. As such I am kindly requesting for a prod in the right direction or so. Thank you everyone!

current topics function in views.py

```
@login_required
def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

Final code after receiving help:
forms.py

```
class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text', 'public']
        labels = {'text': '', 'public' : "Tick to set to public"}
```

models.py

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text
```

views.py

```
def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
    else:
        topics = Topic.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the user is logged in and depending on this filter on only public items, or public items combined with the items for which the user is the owner:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def topics(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        topics = Topic.objects.filter(…)
    else:
        topics = Topic.objects.filter(…)
    topics = topics.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

With `…` the parts you still need to fill in. For the part where the user is authenticated, you will need [**`Q`** objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) to implement a logical *disjunction*.

Comment: Thank you for the help sir! Finally got it :)

Comment: EDIT: Sorry sir, it works fine when I run the server locally but for some reason now even viewing the topics page on my heroku page gives an error.

Comment: @BobTan: exactly what did you fill in for `...`?

Comment: topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')

and

topics = Topic.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('date_added')

Comment: But in case the user is authenticated, you probably both want public posts, and posts by the user, you use a `Q` object for that as specified in the answer. Furthermore of course if you deploy it, the "test" data is lost.

Comment: Sir do you mean like this? 

topics = Topic.objects.get(Q(owner=request.user)&Q(public=True)).order_by('date_added')

and

topics = Topic.objects.get(Q(public=True).order_by('date_added')

, Also what I mean is that on my heroku page clicking topics gives me a internal 500 error, not that there is no data there

Comment: @BobTan: no, it should be with a `|` and use `.filter(...)` not `.get(...)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227139/discussion-between-bob-tan-and-willem-van-onsem).